# Jest tests partially fail: A jest worker process was terminated by another process: signal=SIGABRT, exitCode=null

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, next.js, jestjs

I'm kinda new to Jest and in my Next.js app I have some jest tests that work in other environments, but have not been working in mine for a few days.

This is my `jest.config.js`:

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
    dir: "./",
});

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],

    testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",

    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@/components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1",
        "^@/lib/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/lib/$1",
        "^@/pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/pages/$1",
    },

    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "/node_modules/(?!(.*\\.jsx?)|(.*\\.css?))",
    ],
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(config);
```

My `jest.setup.js` contains just this:

`import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";`

The error I get in the console when running:

`npm run test (jest --watchAll --verbose --coverage)`
is something like this:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: NulError(<a bunch of numbers here>)
fatal runtime error: failed to initiate panic, error 5, 0, 0,
FAIL  __tests__/unit/utils/._formatLongDate.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    A jest worker process (pid=11059) was terminated by another process: signal=SIGABRT, exitCode=null. Operating system logs may contain more information on why this occurred.

      at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:370:23)



 RUNS  __tests__/unit/utils/._formatDecimals.test.js
 RUNS  __tests__/unit/utils/getTodayLong.test.js
 RUNS  __tests__/unit/utils/._getTodayLong.test.js
 RUNS  __tests__/unit/utils/shrinkString.test.js

Test Suites: 4 failed, 6 passed, 10 of 16 total
Tests:       18 passed, 18 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12 s
```

I've tried changing configs and excluding files starting with "._" since my tests don't start like that but in the console I see some like that, but this way it says there are no valid tests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being the following:

I found all the test files starting with `._` and deleted them.